# Clarify ambiguous "names" tag

Tags: discussion, tag

Currently, the [names](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/names) tag has some ambiguity to it: While the three questions currently under it are specifically about the 99 Names of Allah, this tag has also been used for (and subsequently removed from) other questions regarding personal names.

In general, such a vague tag is useless.  If the tag doesn't clearly designate a particular category of questions, it tends to just clutter things up rather than keeping things clean.

So, in the interest of keeping our tagging system both easy to use and easy to navigate, what should we do about this?

Answer (score 3):

I propose that the tag (as currently used) be replaced with [asma-ul-husna](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asma-ul-husna) (i.e., أسماء الحسنى), which is more specifically referring to the Names of Allah as per the following ayah:

> <sup>[20:8](http://quran.com/20/8)</sup> **Allah - there is no deity except Him. To Him belong *al-asma'u-l-husna* (the best Names).**

While we *could* then synonym it to [names](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/names), the ambiguity problem would still remain.  As such, I would suggest retiring the current [names](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/names) tag entirely; if English-language tag synonyms are still desired, creating a new tag, such as [names-of-allah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/names-of-allah) or [99-names](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/99-names), would be much clearer (and thus preferable).

Comment: +1 for replacing with [tag:names-of-allah]

Comment: good idea, "asma-ul-husna" sound quite nice. :)